# AMQP connection closed when nova cells are enabled on Devstack

Tags: 12.04, openstack, rabbitmq

I have set up Devstack on 3 servers having IPs 10.10.1.51,10.10.1.53 and 10.10.1.54. I configured the devstack on server 53(IP 10.10.1.53) as the parent/api cell and configured the openstack on 51 and 54 as child cells. I enabled cells by specifying enable_service n-cell in the respective localrc files. 
The nova.conf in the parent is as follows:

```
[DEFAULT]
    # Swap out the compute_api class so actions are proxied to nova-cells service.
    compute_api_class=nova.compute.cells_api.ComputeCellsAPI

    [cells]
    name=api
    enable=true
    cell_type=api
```

nova.conf in the child cell1 is as follows:

```
[GLOBAL]
# Disable quota checking in child cells.  Let API cell do it exclusively.
quota_driver=nova.quota.NoopQuotaDriver

[cells]
enable=true
name=cell1  # something unique per child cell
cell_type=compute
```

nova.conf in child cell2 is as follows:

```
[GLOBAL]
# Disable quota checking in child cells.  Let API cell do it exclusively.
quota_driver=nova.quota.NoopQuotaDriver

    [cells]
    enable=true
    name=cell1  # something unique per child cell
    cell_type=compute
```

We have the following rabbit server info on the parent cell:

rabbit_host=10.10.1.53 rabbit_port=5672 rabbit_username=admin rabbit_password=password rabbit_virtual_host=api_vhost

And in the child cell named 'cell1' we have the following rabbit server info:

rabbit_host=10.10.1.54 rabbit_port=5673 rabbit_username=admin rabbit_password=password rabbit_virtual_host=cell1_vhost

And in the child cell named 'cell2' we have the following rabbit server info:

rabbit_host=10.10.1.51 rabbit_port=5673 rabbit_username=admin rabbit_password=password rabbit_virtual_host=cell2_vhost

After which I ran the following commands in the API cell to tell about its children:

```
>nova-manage cell create --name=cell1 --cell_type=child --username=admin --password=password --hostname=10.10.1.51 --port=5673 --virtual_host=cell1_vhost --woffset=1.0 --wscale=1.0

>nova-manage cell create --name=cell2 --cell_type=child --username=admin --password=password --hostname=10.10.1.54 --port=5673 --virtual_host=cell1_vhost --woffset=1.0 --wscale=1.0
```

The following command was run in both the child cells to tell them about their parent:

```
>nova-manage cell create --name=api --cell_type=parent --username=admin --password=password --hostname=10.10.1.53 --port=5672 --virtual_host=api_vhost --woffset=1.0 --wscale=1.0
```

n-cell-child and n-cell-region were restarted in all the 3 stack sessions.
n-cell-region of all 3 stack sessions gave an error saying:

```
 2014-07-24 12:54:01.633 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [req-5154ff13-4f6f-4582-8a44-d42941e9a4bc None None] AMQP server 10.10.1.53:5672 closed the connection. Check login credentials: Socket closed
```

n-cell-child screens in both the child cells gave the following error:

```
2014-07-24 12:57:11.579 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [req-ba63e502-f099-4e55-a8e9-297390f5598f None None] AMQP server on 10.10.1.54:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Trying again in 30 seconds.
```

However there is no error in n-cell-child screen of the parent cell. AMQP broker running is rabbitmq-server on all 3 servers. I have checked the users listing in rabbitmq and the credentials seem to be fine.

Any help in debugging the error would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!